# Synonym letters in SharePoint serach

Tags: 2010, search, search-configuration

In alphabet of languages used in my region we have letters đ, č, ć, ž, š. People are used to type search text using English alphabet only. Expected outcome is that search engine will ignore our letters and apply rule:

đ = dj = d

č = c

ć = c

š = s

i.e. if I search for 'skola zivota' search result will include 'škola života'. Google play nice with this https://www.google.com/search?q=skola%20zivota.

How to accomplish this with SharePoint 2010 Search?

I think that thesaurus files and phonetic search can't help me on this. I can't remember exactly how but in SharePoint 2007 there was way to configure this in registry.

Comment: Not sure if it's enough, but I think you have to install the Microsoft Server Speech Platform for each language pack you have installed. This will be required to enable phonetic search. See http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using enterprise search you can set diacritics to be insensitive basically ignoring them but this only applies to the thesaurus feature.

In 2007 you had this:

```
stsadm -o osearchdiacriticsensitive
        -ssp <ssp name>
        [-setstatus <True|False>]
        [-noreset]
```

[**osearchdiacriticsensitive**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262590%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Which is what I think you are thinking of, but I am not sure if it applies to 2010 and I cannot test it.

But it is listed for 2013 [**SharePoint 2013 STSADM**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621084.aspx), so maybe hopefully it didn't skip a generation.

Comment: You're right. Command for SP 2010 is: Set-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity "MyApp" -DiacriticSensitive "False". More info at [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607974.aspx). It is strange that it was false by default but started to work as expected after update.